# Multiple Figures on sidewaysfigure with default numbering

Tags: floats, subfloats, rotating, subcaption

I have two figures I would like to display in landscape on the same page. One is a normal figure, the other is made up of three subfigures.

They are currently in subfigures, to ensure that they end up on the same page.

They are as follows:

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
        \centering
            \input{1.tikz}
        \caption{1}
        \label{fig:1}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
            \input{2a.tikz}
            \caption{2a}
        \end{subfigure}
        %
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
            \input{2b.tikz}
            \caption{2b}
        \end{subfigure}
        %
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
            \input{2c.tikz}
            \caption{2c}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{2 global}
        \label{fig:2}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

With the figures separate they were numbered: `Figure 1`, `(a)`, `(b)`, `(c)`, `Figure 2`.

Whereas now it is `(a)`, ..., `(e)`.

Is there any way to get the original numbering?

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- Don't overuse `subfigure` environments. I suggest that you replace the first `subfigure` environment with a `minipage` environment and that you leave off the second "outer" `subfigure` code entirely.
- Create some vertical separation between Figure 1 and Figure 2 (a,b,c) complex with a `\vspace` instruction.
- Maximize the horizontal separation between the three remaining `subfigure` environments with `\hfill` instructions.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
\documentclass[demo]{article} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        %\input{1.tikz}
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{1.jpg} % choose a suitable width
        \caption{1 global}
        \label{fig:1}
    \end{minipage}

    \vspace{1cm}

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.31\textwidth}
        %\input{2a.tikz}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2a.jpg}
        \caption{2a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.31\textwidth}
        %\input{2b.tikz}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2b.jpg}
        \caption{2b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.31\textwidth}
        %\input{2c.tikz}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2c.jpg}
        \caption{2c}
    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{2 global}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant just what I was looking for! I take it that subfigure doesn't fully encapsulate then? And that the minipage allows for the nested figures?

Comment: @Cjen1 - A `subfigure` environment *is* a fancy `minipage` environment, with one extra facility -- the ability to provide `\caption` and `\label` statements. As the upper figure ("Figure 1") may not need to span the full width of the text block, I recommend placing it in a `minipage` environment to facilitate horizontal centering. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "fully encapsulating" a `subfigure` environment. As `subfigure` environments *are* specialized `minipage` environments, there's no need to encapsulate them further.